# Возведение в степень простым способом

Tags: java, циклы

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать корректное возведение в степень? А то получается что a умножается само на себя, и когда идет 3-ий шаг цикла, то естественно эта a меняется на себя саму же умноженную. Огромная просьба, не предлагать других вариантов реализаций данной функции, укажите пожалуйста на верное решение в контексте этого кода.

```
public class Exponentiation {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(exponentiation(2, 3));

}

public static int exponentiation(int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {

        result = a * a;

    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int result = 1;
...
  result *= a;
```

Comment: Твой пример про бургеры был лучшим, спасибо)